# Why does this requires expression work as a concept but not directly on a function?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts, requires-expression

The following fails to compile.

```cpp
template <typename... U>
requires requires(U... x) { (std::to_string(x) && ...); }
auto to_string(const std::variant<U...>& value) {
    return std::visit([](auto&& value) {
        return std::to_string(std::forward<decltype(value)>(value));
    }, value);
}

int main() {
    std::variant<int, float> v = 42;
    std::cout << to_string(v) << std::endl;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/Wvn6E3PG5

If I convert the direct requires expression into a concept though, it works fine.

```cpp
template<typename T, typename... U>
concept to_stringable = requires(U... u) { (std::to_string(u) && ...); };

template <to_stringable... U>
auto to_string(const std::variant<U...>& value) {
    return std::visit([](auto&& value) {
        return std::to_string(std::forward<decltype(value)>(value));
    }, value);
}

int main() {
    std::variant<int, float> v = 42;
    std::cout << to_string(v) << std::endl;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/W6znbvTzo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you have:

```cpp
template <to_stringable... U>
auto to_string(const std::variant<U0, U1>& value) {
```

This checks if each individual type satisfies `to_stringable<T>`, so it is essentially equivalent to:

```
template <to_stringable U0, to_stringable U1>
auto to_string(const std::variant<U0, U1>& value) {
```

And with just one argument `T` your concept is:

```cpp
requires(T t) { (std::to_string(t)); };
```

However, with more than one argument, it looks like:

```cpp
requires(T1 t1, T2 t2) { (std::to_string(t1) && std::to_string(t2)); }
```

Which doesn't work because you can't `&&` two `std::string`s, so the constraint is not satisfied.

What you really want to do is fold over a constraint:

```cpp
template <typename... U>
requires ((requires(U x) { std::to_string(x); }) && ...)
```

... Which gcc doesn't seem to implement properly because of [a bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=102777) but you can get away with:

```cpp
template <typename... U>
requires requires(U... x) { ((void) std::to_string(x), ...); }
```

Comment: "*And with just one argument T your concept is:*" Actually, it's equivalent to `true`. Remember: the concept takes a `T` followed by a pack of `U`.

Answer (score 3):

You did not *exactly* convert it into a concept. This would be an exact conversion into a concept:

```
template<typename... U>
concept real_to_stringable = requires(U... u) { (std::to_string(u) && ...); };

template <typename ...U>
   requires real_to_stringable<U...>
auto to_string(const std::variant<U...>& value) {
    return std::visit([](auto&& value) {
        return std::to_string(std::forward<decltype(value)>(value));
    }, value);
}
```

And it gives the same error. For the same reason: `std::to_string` returns a `basic_string`. Which does not have a && overload. And therefore, &&ing them all together doesn't compile. So the constraint is not satisfied.

The reason your version of the concept code *appears* to work is because you didn't do it right. A concept whose first parameter is a type is a "type concept". A type concept can be used in place of a typename in certain circumstances as a shorthand for adding a `requires` constraint.

The first template parameter for such a concept is filled in with the type given as an argument to the template being constrained. The *other* template parameters for the concept are filled in by the other arguments provided at the point of the concept's use. But... you didn't provide any; `to_stringable` wasn't *given* other arguments in the template header. So the `U` in your `to_stringable` is always an empty set. Which means the constraint is always satisfied.

That is, `template<to_stringable ...U>` produces a requires constraint equivalent to `requires (to_stringable<U> && ...)`, not `requires to_stringable<U...>`.